# Windows 11 Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)

Tags: usb, drivers, motherboard, windows-11

Wondering if anyone's seen this before.. I have an asrock x299 taichi xe motherboard with really nothing exciting on top -- a couple RAM sticks, an old GTX1080, and a couple crucial nvmes in RAID5. I tossed windows 11 on, and am getting the dreaded "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" in device manager. I don't actually have anything plugged into my USB ports, and the hubs appear to be showing up just fine.

The usual tricks of enhanced power mode, disabling fast start, etc. didn't help. Given I don't actually have any USB devices plugged in, I'm assuming its something that sits on the USB bus thats on the motherboard, but I can't figure out what it would be. The LAN ports, wifi, and bluetooth all show up just fine.. Given Windows won't tell me a hardware ID -- or anything at all really, anyone have any idea how i might figure out what this device is? I'm sure it probably just needs a driver, but i can't find one until i figure out what "it" is..

Comment: boot a "live" linux system, then you can use `lsusb` command to list all USB devices - edit: `Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' }` in powershell may help

Comment: I am not saying that I know what the problem is (I don't) but "Device Descriptor Request Failed" doesn't sound like needing a specific driver unless somehow it is tied to the controller itself and I have written many USB drivers.  My first guess would be to update your MB firmware (aka BIOS)

Comment: Get-PnPDevice just shows it as unknown with no details.. lsusb from a live CD doesn't even appear to show a device..